# Como actualizo un input si el checkbox es clickeado con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Lo que necesito hacer(y que aun no me resulta) es que si el cliente clickea el checkbox OrigenAeropuerto en el input DireccionOrigen tome el value del checkbox o en su defecto pueda definirle un valor a ese input que es obligatorio.

```html
<label><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Origen</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="OrigenAeropuerto" value="Aeropuerto SCL">
<i class='fa fa-plane'></i> Aeropuerto?

<input type="text" name="DireccionOrigen" id="geocomplete_origen" class="form-control input-sm" required/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esto haces que al pulsar el checkbox o el input se ponga el valor de este en el input

```js
function ponValor(){
  valor = document.getElementById("chk").value;
document.getElementById("geocomplete_origen").value = valor
}
```

```html
    <label><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Origen</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="OrigenAeropuerto" value="Aeropuerto SCL" id="chk" onclick="ponValor()">
    <i class='fa fa-plane'></i> Aeropuerto?

    <input type="text" name="DireccionOrigen" id="geocomplete_origen" class="form-control input-sm" onclick="ponValor()" required/>
```

Aunque como dices que es un valor obligatorio lo suyo es que cuando envies el formulario valides que el valor tenga datos con un if y que luego llames al metodo que envia los datos si se ha validado correctamente:

```
if(document.getElementById("chk").value == "" || document.getElementById("chk").value == null){validado = false};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solución para mostrar el valor del checkbock en el input

```
<script>
function accion(e){
alert(e.value);
var valor_checkbox=e.value;
document.getElementById("geocomplete_origen").value=valor_checkbox;
}
</script>
<label><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Origen</label>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="accion(this);" name="OrigenAeropuerto" value="Aeropuerto SCL">
<i class='fa fa-plane'></i> Aeropuerto?

<input type="text" name="DireccionOrigen" id="geocomplete_origen" class="form-control input-sm" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si usas [jQuery](https://jquery.com) Puedes hacerlo con el siguiente código:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#OrigenAeropuerto").on("click", function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked") && !$("DireccionOrigen").val()){
   $("DireccionOrigen").val($(this).val())
  }
 })
})
<script>
<label><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Origen</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="OrigenAeropuerto" value="Aeropuerto SCL">
<i class='fa fa-plane'></i> Aeropuerto?

<input type="text" name="DireccionOrigen" id="geocomplete_origen" class="form-control input-sm" required/>
```

Ahora si quieres hacerlo con [javascript](https://www.javascript.com/), entonces usa el siguiente código:

```
<script>
function OrigenAeropuerto_checked() {
 var i = document.getElementById("geocomplete_origen");
 if ( this.checked && !i.value ) {
  i.value = this.value;
 }
}
</script>
<label><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Origen</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="OrigenAeropuerto" value="Aeropuerto SCL" onClick="OrigenAeropuerto_checked()">
<i class='fa fa-plane'></i> Aeropuerto?

<input type="text" name="DireccionOrigen" id="geocomplete_origen" class="form-control input-sm" required/>
```

Quedara a tu elección cual método usar, sin embargo es importante aclarar que **jQuery** tiende a hacer todo mucho mas fácil a pesar que en este ejemplo dicha ventaja no es notable.

Espero haber ayudado, Saludos!... ;))